# arangosh fails to load Graph module

Tags: graph, import, arangodb

I tried to import [IMDB graph from the official examples](https://github.com/arangodb/example-datasets/blob/master/Graphs/IMDB/import.sh) and the error occurred on system modules importing.
Can you please explain why the graph module can't be loaded and how can it be fixed?

```
arangosh (ArangoDB 3.0.10 [linux] 64bit, using VPack 0.1.30, ICU 54.1, V8 5.0.71.39, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014)

0.0.0.0:8529@_system> var db = require("org/arangodb").db;

0.0.0.0:8529@_system> var Graph = require("org/arangodb/graph").Graph;
JavaScript exception in file 'common/bootstrap/modules.js' at 447,9: ArangoError 3100: cannot locate module
File: @arangodb/graph
!        throw e;
!        ^
stacktrace: ArangoError: cannot locate module
File: @arangodb/graph
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (common/bootstrap/modules.js:524:11)
    at Function.Module._load (common/bootstrap/modules.js:443:25)
    at global.require (common/bootstrap/modules.js:633:17)
    at <shell command>:1:13
```

As it found the graph.js module is located in the `APP` directory:

```
$ find /usr/share/arangodb3/js/  -name "*graph.*" -type f
/usr/share/arangodb3/js/apps/system/_admin/aardvark/APP/frontend/js/models/graph.js
/usr/share/arangodb3/js/apps/system/_admin/aardvark/APP/frontend/js/graphViewer/test_data/graph.txt
/usr/share/arangodb3/js/common/modules/@arangodb/general-graph.js
/usr/share/arangodb3/js/common/modules/@arangodb/graph-examples/example-graph.js
```

What should be the correct import path to import `graph.js`?

Answer (score 2):

`$ arangorestore --input-directory "dump"` allows to solve the issue and import .json collections of vertices and edges. However, afterwards the imported collections should be manually bound to the manually created graph object.

It's a shame that official examples do not work... **Can anybody please explain how to import the `graph.js` module?**

Note that there is also `general-graph.js` module available, but it has only the `._addVertexCollection()` function and lacks the corresponding analogue for the edges. **Is it possible to use `general-graph.js` module to import the whole graph and how can it be done?**

PS  It's a shame to have broken examples in the documentation and does not have the comprehensive description of how to import graphs into the production-level Graph Database.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that `org/arangodb/graph` was removed in latest version. It's present in v2.8.

Using v3.1 I imported this dataset (for education purposes) with the next approach:

`$ arangorestore --server.database Test --input-directory "path/to/IMDB/dump"`

all options can be found in [documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/2.8/HttpBulkImports/Arangorestore.html)

then run Web interface http://localhost:8529 and switch to 'Graphs' 
add a new graph with params:
Name: marvel_heros

Edge Definitions: marvel_edges

From collections: marvel_vertices

To collections: marvel_vertices